# JComboBox changes JTextField width after inserting in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am trying to add 3 combo boxes for a person's date of birth: one for month, then day, then year. When I add all 3 combo boxes, it changes the width of the `JTextFields`. Any help on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Also is there a better way to add in the months for the `JComboBox`, instead of inserting it one by one?

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Home extends JFrame {

    private JButton btnClear, btnNext;
    private JTextField txtName, txtAddress, txtCity, txtState,
            txtZipCode, txtPhoneNumber, txtEmail;
    private JComboBox txtDate, txtYear, txtMonth;
    private JLabel labelName, labelAddress, labelCity, labelState,
            labelZipCode, labelPhoneNumber, labelEmail, labelDOB;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Home().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public Home() {
        createView();

        setTitle("Job Hiring Systems");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 500);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 500));
        //pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    private void createView() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(25,10,25,10));
        getContentPane().add(panel);

        /*
                 * North Panel
         */
        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        panel.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel labelWelcomeMessage = new JLabel("Welcome to the Job Hiring Systems");
        labelWelcomeMessage.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25));
        northPanel.add(labelWelcomeMessage, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        /*
                 * End of North Panel
         */

 /*
                 * Center Panel
         */
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        centerPanel.setSize(300, 300);
        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();

        centerPanel.setLayout(layout);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        labelName = new JLabel("Enter your name: ");
        labelName.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        centerPanel.add(labelName, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        txtName = new JTextField(25);
        txtName.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        txtName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        centerPanel.add(txtName, gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        labelAddress = new JLabel("Enter your address: ");
        labelAddress.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        centerPanel.add(labelAddress, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        txtAddress = new JTextField(25);
        txtAddress.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        txtAddress.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        centerPanel.add(txtAddress, gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        labelCity = new JLabel("Enter your city: ");
        labelCity.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        centerPanel.add(labelCity, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        txtCity = new JTextField(25);
        txtCity.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        txtCity.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        centerPanel.add(txtCity, gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        labelState = new JLabel("Enter your State: ");
        labelState.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        centerPanel.add(labelState, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        txtState = new JTextField(25);
        txtState.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        txtState.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        centerPanel.add(txtState, gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        labelZipCode = new JLabel("Enter your Zip Code: ");
        labelZipCode.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        centerPanel.add(labelZipCode, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        txtZipCode = new JTextField(25);
        txtZipCode.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        txtZipCode.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        centerPanel.add(txtZipCode, gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        labelPhoneNumber = new JLabel("Enter your Phone Number: ");
        labelPhoneNumber.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        centerPanel.add(labelPhoneNumber, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        txtPhoneNumber = new JTextField(25);
        txtPhoneNumber.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        txtPhoneNumber.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        centerPanel.add(txtPhoneNumber, gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 6;
        labelEmail = new JLabel("Enter your Email: ");
        labelEmail.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        centerPanel.add(labelEmail, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 6;
        txtEmail = new JTextField(25);
        txtEmail.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        txtEmail.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        centerPanel.add(txtEmail, gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 7;
        labelDOB = new JLabel("Enter your Date of Birth: ");
        labelDOB.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        centerPanel.add(labelDOB, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        txtMonth = new JComboBox();
        txtMonth.addItem("January");
        txtMonth.addItem("February");
        txtMonth.addItem("March");
        txtMonth.addItem("April");
        txtMonth.addItem("May");
        txtMonth.addItem("June");
        txtMonth.addItem("July");
        txtMonth.addItem("August");
        txtMonth.addItem("September");
        txtMonth.addItem("October");
        txtMonth.addItem("November");
        txtMonth.addItem("December");
        centerPanel.add(txtMonth, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        txtDate = new JComboBox();
        for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
            txtDate.addItem(i);
        }
        centerPanel.add(txtDate, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        txtYear = new JComboBox();
        for (int i = 1940; i < 2017; i++) {
            txtYear.addItem(i);
        }
        centerPanel.add(txtYear, gbc);
        panel.add(centerPanel);

        /*
                 * End of Center Panel
         */

 /*
                 * South Panel
         */
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        panel.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        btnClear = new JButton("CLEAR");
        southPanel.add(btnClear, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        btnNext = new JButton("NEXT");
        southPanel.add(btnNext, BorderLayout.WEST);
        /*
                 * End of South Panel
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify how you would like your JTextFields to look like ?

Comment: I wanted the JTextFields to be the same length of the 3 JComboBox, but before adding the JComboBox, I set the text fields length to 25 pixels but after adding the combo box, all the text fields width was shorter

Comment: The number you pass to the `JTextField` constructor is the columns, not the pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I add all 3 combo boxes, it changes the width of the JTextFields. Any help on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Each component in a `GridBagLayout` takes up 1 cell (one space vertically and 1 horizontally) by default. Each time you add a combo box, you increase the number of columns in the grid, but the text fields still take 1 horizontal space, aligning themselves with the first combo box.

[image]

You want the text fields to align themselves with the last combo box, or in other words, to take whatever space remains in the grid. You can do that by specifying

```
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
```

for your text fields. (In your case `gbc.gridwidth = 3` would also work, but you might need to change that if you add more components.)

Note that since the layout manager assigns space to the components, specifying a number in the constructor of the text fields won't do much,

> Also is there a better way to add in the months for the JComboBox, instead of inserting it one by one.

Yes, I suggest you take advantage of the new Date-Time API. There is an [Enum Month](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) that has your constants readied. Don't forget to specify the generic type for your combo boxes:

```
JComboBox<Month> txtMonth = new JComboBox<>();
for (Month month : Month.values())
    txtMonth.addItem(month);
```

And I'll leave you do correct the capitalization yourself (hint: `getDisplayName`).

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, you can directly create your JComboBox with an array of months :

```
String[] months = {"January", ..., "December"}; // put all the months here
JComboBox txtMonth = new JComboBox(months);
```

**EDIT :**

For your first question : if you want every JTextField to have the same length as the three JComboBox together, then you should write `gbc.gridwidth = 3;` before adding any JTextField.

See more here (mostly the example in the middle, it is really clear) : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: Thanks for the help